# Проблемы с установкой Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Пытаюсь поставить Ubuntu 20.04 вместе с Windows 10, но в процессе установки gparted не указывает, что Windows оже установлена на мой компьютер. Быстрый запуск отключён. Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы в gparted появилась Windows. Через ручную разметку диска работать не могу, т.к. запутался там и я ещё новичок в этом. Также могу сказать, что кроме дисков C:\ и D:\ у меня есть свободное место с размером около 95 Гб.

Comment: Вообщем Вы в правильном направлении, пробуйте включать и переключать в биосе все что касается режимов загрузки и секьюрити.

Comment: Переустановил Windows, думая, что не работает что-то в нём, всё равно не видит

Comment: Скрин гпартеда было бы неплохо приложить сюда.